# Rest client data into Java object. Getting com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a sample backend response coming as below:
When I try to map this response into the java object, I am getting following error.

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.mc.membersphere.model.MemberSummaryLabel[]` out of START_OBJECT token

Seems like the issue with the body tag coming from API. Which has array of objects. I need help, how to handle this body tag arrays value in Java mapping?

```
    Backend API Response:
  {
   "body": [{

            "pcp": "KASSAM, Far",
             "er12M": "0",
             "ipAdmits12M": "0",
             "ipReAdmits12M": "0",
             "rx12M": "0",
             "pastMedicalHistory": " ",
             "erCost12M": "0.0"

             }
          ]
      }
```

Java Program to get the Rest data into the Java objects is as below.

```
   import java.util.Collections;
   import java.util.Properties;
   import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
   import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
   import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
   import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
   import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
   import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
   import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
   import com.mc.membersphere.model.MemberSummaryLabel;
   import com.mc.membersphere.utility.PropertyUtil;

   public class TestRestclient implements CommandLineRunner{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApi.class, args); }

private static Properties prop = PropertyUtil.getProperties();

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    String getMVPSummaryUrl = prop.getProperty("getmvpmembersummary.url");

    String url = getMVPSummaryUrl+"/"+"CA";

    ResponseEntity<MemberSummaryLabel[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,entity, MemberSummaryLabel[].class);
    if(response.getStatusCode()== HttpStatus.OK) {
    for(MemberSummaryLabel memberSummaryLabel : response.getBody())
    {
        System.out.println(memberSummaryLabel.pcp);
    }
    //System.out.println("Print response" + response);
}
else {
    System.out.println("Error");
}

}
}
```

MemberSummaryLabel is as below.

```
      import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
      public class MemberSummaryLabel {
      @JsonProperty("pcp")
      public String pcp;
      @JsonProperty("er12M")
      public Integer er12M;
      @JsonProperty("ipAdmits12M")
      public Integer ipAdmits12M;
      @JsonProperty("ipReAdmits12M")
      public Integer ipReAdmits12M;
      @JsonProperty("rx12M")
      public Integer rx12M;
      @JsonProperty("pastMedicalHistory")
      public String pastMedicalHistory;
      @JsonProperty("erCost12M")
      public Double erCost12M;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see, its an issue with your mapping. Your response is in "body" and *body* contains list of *MemberSummaryLabel*. So, you need to have one more class as mentioned below,

```
public class Body{
   @JsonProperty("body")
   public List<MemberSummaryLabel> memberSummaryLabelList;
}
```

And your *exchange* method should return *NewClass*.

```
 ResponseEntity<Body> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,entity, Body.class);
```

And for, iteration use,

```
for(MemberSummaryLabel memberSummaryLabel : response.getBody().getMemberSummaryLabelList()){
}
```

Comment: I got your point. You are right. one small issue. I am getting casting error on the iteration line. So its trying to cast to MemberSummaryLabel or to what?I am bit confused.

Comment: Can you add stack trace? As per my understanding you should not get casting exception.

Comment: its giving compliation error and says - The method getMemberSummaryLabelList() is undefined for the type ResponseEntity<Body>

Comment: did you add _getter_ and _setter_. I have not added that code. :) Just add those method. If you are using _lombork_ then just add _getter_ and _setter_ annotation.

Comment: already added the getter setter. Still giving the same error. :(

Comment: ohh.. try _response.getBody().getMemberSummaryLabelList()_